# Russian language is showing question mark in oscommerce

Tags: oscommerce

I really don't know what happened but suddenly my website is showing question mark in both frontend and backend in oscommerce. Everything was working fine but suddenly it stopped working perhaps one of my colleague did something. Format of my db structure is in latin1_swedish_ci table name: products_description. i dont know if before it was in utf8 format or not. Can anyone tell me how to solve it if i change the structure to utf8 format will it work back to normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a solution, table name field was in latin1_swedish_ci so when i converted it into utf8_general_ci it fixed my solution. Now i am able to store russian data into database properly but what was not fixed is all the previously data which was in ?(question mark) is of no use i have to re-add them again